# How to simply pass a variable in a regex replace statement?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable string phrase, and I want to trim out the beginning of the string with contents from a variable, with or w/o a blank space.

```
var fullphrase = "how can I trim this phrase?";
var cutthis = "how Can i";
var result = fullphrase.replace("/^cutthis ?/i","");
```

I want result to be = "trim this phrase?"

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not pass the variable into the replace parameter?

```
var fullphrase = "how can I trim this phrase?";
var cutthis = "how Can i";
var result = fullphrase.replace(new RegExp("^" + cutthis + " ?", 'i'),"");
```

Comment: you can NOT put quotes around regex...at least i have never found anyone do it. This doesn't work.. use RegExp function.

Comment: Yea I forgot to add the regexp class.

Comment: Well don't feel bad i didn't even know of this till yesterday

Answer (score 3):

```
var fullphrase = "how can I trim this phrase?";
var cutthis = "how Can i";
var result = fullphrase.replace(new RegExp('^' + cutthis + ' ?', 'i') ,"");
```

Comment: This regex is slightly different. Not sure if it'll provide a different result though. Mine was slightly edited afterwards. I forgot the new RegExp part. :P

Comment: Oh, I see. SO, erases the edit history during the first x minutes. Kind of annoying

Comment: @dab borrowed the `' ?'` bit.

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically build the pattern use the `RegExp` object:

```
var fullphrase = "how can I trim this phrase?";
var cutthis = "how Can i";
var pattern = "^" + cutthis + " ?";
var re = new RegExp(pattern, "i");
var result = fullphrase.replace(re,"");
console.log(result);
```

Check out a [JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/xepaside/1/edit?js,console) of this in action.

Comment: This definitely gives me a clear understanding of js regexp, but I will use the smaller block in production. Thanks!